# Fixing dump files in ida

Tags: ida, dumping

ive recently dumped a few mem page sections of a possibly malicious dll. However, I can't analyze the files correctly since i don't know how to allign all the sections correctly for analysis at once in IDA. I can analyze them individually but many values are displayed in red under names like v123456789. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: If you can, dump the complete memory region of the dll, it'll save some trouble

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't possible as it seems that the module gets split and mapped into different parts of the process upon injection.

Answer (score 2):

> If possible, please try to dump modules together.

If that is not possible, load any of them in IDA and go to `File -> Load file -> Additional binary file` to load each file one after another. After selecting the file, IDA will display the following dialog:

[image]

Here you have to make sure that each part is loaded at the right offset.

Comment: I have been doing this, however, my issue is trying to find the correct offset to load the next section at.

Comment: @BobBobby I'm sorry, I'm afraid there is not much you could do about it other than regenerating the dumps with annotated offsets. There is no way for IDA to know how to align them.

Comment: What do you mean by annotated offsets? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm sort of new to using IDA

Comment: @BobBobby The term *offset* refers to their starting address in memory (e.g. page at 0x40000 should be loaded at that address)

Comment: Okay thanks, sorry for misunderstanding. Do you know how I could go about finding the correct loading segment offset for loading the next bin file though?

Comment: If you have no idea where the segments were in memory, it will be quiet hard (if not impossible) to find the correct ones, especially if there are gaps

Comment: I have the exact range of where each bin file was in memory from the dump I made. However, there are gaps between them. Do I just put the beginning of this range into loading segment address then? I'm not that familiar with IDA...

Comment: Try zeroing the loading segment and using the start address of each part as the loading offset. that should do the trick

Comment: I tried what you did. It fixed many of the missing values however it turned some of them into unk_ and flt_ variables. Could this be due to my loading settings on the first bin file. I'm loading the text section first... Not sure

Comment: I often encounter unk_ variables in IDA when working with malware. It just means that it is a global variable which is not set at initialization, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Is there a way to get the value of these global variables?

Comment: Did you try looking for cross-references?

Comment: Yes, I did. Looking at the xrefs from it I see unk_12345 and a list of hexadecimal values after it (one by one in a table). I'm not sure which of the values is the correct one...

Comment: I figured out the flt_123[x] ones because the xrefs led me to an array and the value was stored at index x. However, when it comes to the unk variables I can't figure out which value in the table I should use.